# Can't mount SD card - Wrong filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, sd-card

Just bought a SanDisk microSDHC 8Gb card and tried to change the file system to ntfs (used cfdisk thru terminal). Couldn't mount the device. Tried to change back to FAT32, but still can't mount. Running: sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt -t vfat I get this result:

```
 mount: wrong filesystem, invalid option,
   bad superblock in /dev/mmcblk0p1, ...
```

Also, the log for dmesg:

```
[13891.357486]  mmcblk0: p1
[13933.891942]  mmcblk0: p1
[13974.716677]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[14149.721862] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[14149.722387] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[14149.722841] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[14149.723275] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[14149.723278] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[14157.995849] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[14157.995864] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Can't find a valid FAT filesyste
```

Nodes seem gold. lsblk gives me:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0 461,9G  0 part /
├─sda2        8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5        8:5    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7,4G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   7,5M  0 part 
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   7,4G  0 part
```

cfdisk is running ok. Also, nothing returns from fdisk -l.
(Running Linux Mint 17)

Any ideas on how can I mount?

EDIT: I formated using `sudo fdisk`. dmesg is recognizing when I plug it in:

```
arthur@arthur-Aspire-5750 /sys/block $ dmesg | tail
[15755.832422] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p2): bogus number of reserved sectors
[15755.832437] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[16074.307482]  mmcblk0: p1
[16183.923340]  mmcblk0: p1
[16247.504268] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[16247.504274] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[16312.973630] mmc0: card aaaa removed
[16314.429559] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[16314.429919] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SS08G 7.40 GiB 
[16314.439371]  mmcblk0: p1
```

However I still can't mount (same wrong filesystem error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7,4G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   7,5M  0 part 
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0   7,4G  0 part
```

mmcblk0p1 is only 7,5 MB large, you probably meant to run

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt
```

Edit
Remember that it's not sufficient to change the partition type using `cfdisk`, you also need to format the partition.

Comment: Running sudo mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt gives me the same bad superblock error.

   `$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt -t vfat[sudo]
    mount: tipo de sistema de arquivos incorreto, opção inválida, superbloco inválido em /dev/mmcblk0p2, página de código ou programa
       auxiliar faltando ou outro erro
       Em alguns casos, informações úteis são encontradas no
       syslog - tente "dmesg | tail" ou algo assim`

Comment: But you did format the partition, did you? Edited answer...

Comment: I do believe yes. I ran `fdisk`, and then "w". Is there a way I can check that?

Comment: That is not enough, you only changed the partition type. Now format the partition using `mkfs`.

Comment: @user3277414  Did you find any solution ? I am also stuck in the same issue.